# Vehicle 2 Vehicle Communication Code

Tags: python

I have written a code to enable V2V communication between two automated vehicles. However, it doesn't work as expected. The controller basically calls the sending data method in another code with a list of waypoint. The data is then received by other ports. However m ports are not receiving the data at all.

In the controller code, I have made every vehicle a thread. Therefore, each thread accesses this class. I hope I have explained it properly here.

```
 class V2V_comm():
        global ports
        def __init__(self,port):
            self.host = "127.0.0.1"
            self.port = port
            self.skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.skt.bind((self.host,self.port))
            self.skt.settimeout(1)
            self.loc_info = []
            self.receiving_data()

        def sending_data(self,wp):
            try:
                message = wp
                for port in ports:
                    if port != self.port:
                        print "Sending location of: ", self.port

                        self.skt.sendto(str(message),("127.0.0.1",port))
            except:
                print "Unable to send message from: ", self.port

        def receiving_data(self):

            try:
                print "Trying to receive data at: ", self.port
                data,addr = self.skt.recvfrom(1024)
                #print "The points received are: ", str(data)
                #print "The points are received at: ", self.port
                self.loc_info.append(data)
                print self.loc_info, "for port: ", self.port

            except:
                print "Unable to receive message at: ", self.port
```

Comment: Do you create an instance of this `V2V_comm` class per thread? Do they all have the same port, or different ports? Who calls `sending_data` and where is `global ports` updated?

Comment: Yes, I create this instance per thread. Every thread has a different port. As you can see in the init function, the port is passed for every thread. So basically the "controller" of every thread calls the sending data. Its basically what you would expect in real life. Every vehicle (thread) in the code has a controller that takes care of V2V communication. Global ports are not updated. Basically these are the ports of the vehicle. So I have created a list that contains the ports of all the vehicles in the network. So one port sends its trajectory to all other ports except itself.

Comment: You do understand why all this information should be in the question, right? You're also missing a message loop (whenever you create an instance, it reads exactly one message from its port, but you should presumably be calling `receiving_data` in a loop elsewhere). You also don't show any of the logic you describe, or the output from your code.

Comment: I believe you have to use `0.0.0.0` as IP address instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Useless You are right...my fault. This is the output of my code. You can see that one vehicle receives data from another, but the other vehicle doesn't receives the data.
Got sensor data for thread-1
sensor okay
Got sensor data for thread-2
Got sensor data for thread-1

Got sensor data for thread-2

Trying to receive data at:  30151  
Trying to receive data at:  30152  
Unable to receive message at:  30151  
Sending location of:  30151  
(0, 1275, 10)['[(0, 1275, 10)]']  
 for port:  30152  
Sending location of:  30152  
(0, -1275, 10)  
Reached goal   
No more waypoints

Comment: Please edit that into the question, so it's readable. If you can't just ask a new question including it - the goal is ideally a minimal self-contained example that others can actually run and understand.